# Java sort list object by date ascending

Tags: java, sorting

I'd like to sort list of my objects by one argument it's date in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"  by ascending order. I can't find a right solution. In python It's easily to sort it using lambda, but in Java I've a problem with it.

```
for (Shop car : cars) {
             Collections.sort(cars, new Comparator<Shop>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final Shop car, final Shop car) {
                    return car.getDate().compareTo(arc.getDate());
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it a date or string of that type? if it is a date which java object do you use?

Comment: It's a string of that type

Comment: Show some actual code of what you've tried. Is this Java 8? if not that's very important.

Comment: I've only list of data objects of myOwnClass, and used Collection.sort(thatList);

Comment: But it doesn't work

Comment: check my updated answer and please tell me if it works because I dont have test data here

Comment: Ok please wait a moment

Comment: Using the two-arg `Collections.sort()` is a good idea. You don’t want to do it in a loop. Other than this and a typo in the parameter list, your code should work. You shouldn’t have `car` twice in `(final Shop car, final Shop car)`, you probably meant `arc` the second time.

Comment: Tip: Use only the java.time classes, never the `Date` & `Calendar` classes.

Comment: On one hand the asker doesn’t need any date-time classes at all since the natural ordering of the strings is the order s/he wants. On the other hand, for most purposes it would probably be more convenient to store the date as a `java.time.LocalDateTime` inside the `Shop` object. Also @BasilBourque

Comment: @stackish, in the question you write that the dates have format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`, but in comments to a couple of the answers you say it’s `yyyy-MM-dd` only. You are not making it easy to help you with a working solution. No matter which is correct I still mean what I’ve said in my two previous comments though (except if you don’t want to have hours and minutes, it should be `LocalDate` rather than `LocalDateTime`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try that. I think it will work:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        Stream<Date> sorted = l.stream().map(a->{
            try {
                return f.parse(a);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }).sorted();
```

UPDATE:
and if you want a list:

```
List sorted = l.stream().map(a->{
            try {
                return f.parse(a);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

UPDATED: (as question updated using "cars")

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        List<Car> sorted = cars.stream().sorted(
                (a,b)->
        {
            try {
                return f.parse(a.getDate()).compareTo(f.parse(b.getDate()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it would be much clearer without that ParseException...:| but its throwing it so we have to deal with it

Comment: And where I've to put my list of objects, is it this  L (lowerCase) ?

Comment: I implemented it for your list "cars"

Comment: It works thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

> **public boolean before(Date when)**
>
> true if and only if the instant of time represented by this Date
>   object is strictly earlier than the instant represented by when; false
>   otherwise.

please refer java docs for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-

Or you can use **after** method from Date Class inplace of **before**

```
package com.stackoverflow.DataSortReverse;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

class Car{
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Car(String name, Date date) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [date=" + date + "]";
    }
}

public class DateSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        try {
            carList.add(new Car("car1",dateFormat.parse("2017-01-10")));
            carList.add(new Car("car1",dateFormat.parse("2017-02-10")));
            carList.add(new Car("car1",dateFormat.parse("2017-02-30")));
            carList.add(new Car("car1",dateFormat.parse("2017-01-09")));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        /*
         * if you wish to change sorting order just 
         * replace -1 with 1 and 1 with -1
         * 
         * 
         * date1.before(date2)  returns true when date1 comes before date2 
         * in calendar
         * 
         * java docs :: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-
         * */
        Collections.sort(carList, new Comparator<Car>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
                if(o1.getDate().before(o2.getDate())){
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(carList);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java 8:

```
 DateTimeFormatter fm = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
 objects.sort((o1, o2) -> LocalDateTime.parse(o1.getDateStr(), fm)
                    .compareTo(LocalDateTime.parse(o2.getDateStr(), fm)));
```

And java 7:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Collections.sort(objects, new Comparator<YourObjectType>() {
            public int compare(YourObjectType o1, YourObjectType o2) {
                try {
                    return df.parse(o1.getDateStr()).compareTo(df.parse(o2.getDateStr()));
                } catch(ParseException pe) {
                    // handle the way you want...
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean solution without `ParseException`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(shop -> LocalDateTime.parse(shop.getDate(), formatter)));
```

Comment: It shows me an error:  Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-04-02' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-04-02 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: so its better without the exception, but not without the exception handling :D

Comment: @stackish I think, this is because some of your dates do not contain the time part (e.g. `2017-04-02` instead of `2017-04-02 12:00`).

Comment: I've change all my dates to format "YYYY-MM-DD" without hours and still give me exceptions

Comment: @stackish Use `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. `YYYY` and `DD` mean a bit different things.

Answer (score -1):

A revision of my solution. If you define the following comparator class...

```
class ShopDateComparator implements Comparator<Shop> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Shop shop1, Shop shop2) {
    return shop1.getDate().toLowerCase().compareTo(shop2.getDate().toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

...then all you need to do sort `cars` (which I’m assuming is a list of objects of type `Shop`) is:

```
Collections.sort(cars, new ShopDateComparator());
```

Comment: but I've a List<Shop> cars     , and inside it I've a date as string in format "YYYY-MM-DD" and i'd like to sort by this date

Comment: My answer was just a guide, and the solution specific to your code would be quite similar: `Collections.sort(cars, (Shop shop1, Shop shop2) -> shop1.date.toLowerCase().compareTo(shop2.date.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: It doesn't work, i've tried your solution

Comment: I’ve revised my answer — check it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: @JoeydeVilla The `.toLowerCase()` are actually not needed, because the strings don't contain any letters, only `0123456789:- ` according to the
used date-time format.

Comment: You’re right — it’s not absolutely necessary, but I generally add `.toLowerCase()` in my string comparators as a safety measure against typos, mis-entered data, and the like.