# Sort Array object by date of its field

Tags: java

I have an Object `MyTimes` and in that object there are fields `name` ,`start_date` and `configuration`.

I have an array of this object, `MyTimes [] mytimes`

I am trying to sort the array by the start time but am struggling how to go about it.

The `start_time` field is a string, so this needs converting to a datetime.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");


for(int i=0; i<mytimes.length; i++) {
   Date date = formatter.parse(mytimes[i].getStartTime());
}
```

I'd then put the date into an array list perhaps and then sort by datetime? But then I wouldnt know which start_time corresponds with which `mytimes` object...

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the old java date API instead of the new modern `java.time`?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also make sure that `start_date` is an `Instant` (not a `String`), it makes everything and in particular the sorting much more straightforward.

Comment: Adapt the Java 8 solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43426855/5772882) to your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the right circumstances this is a one-liner:

```
    Arrays.sort(myTimes, Comparator.comparing(MyTimes::getStartDate));
```

Let’s see it in action:

```
    MyTimes[] myTimes = {
            new MyTimes("Polly", "2019-03-06T17:00:00Z"),
            new MyTimes("Margaret", "2019-03-08T09:00:00Z"),
            new MyTimes("Jane", "2019-03-01T06:00:00Z")
    };

    Arrays.sort(myTimes, Comparator.comparing(MyTimes::getStartDate));

    Arrays.stream(myTimes).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> ```
> Jane     2019-03-01T06:00:00Z
> Polly    2019-03-06T17:00:00Z
> Margaret 2019-03-08T09:00:00Z
> ```

I am assuming that `getStartDate` returns an `Instant` or another type the natural order of which agrees with the chronological order you want. For example:

```
public class MyTimes {

    private String name;
    private Instant startDate;

    // Constructor, getters, toString, etc.
}
```

If you are receiving your start dates as strings somehow, you may write a convenient constructor that accepts a string for start date. I am already using such a constructor in the above snippet. One possibility is having two constructors:

```
public MyTimes(String name, Instant startDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public MyTimes(String name, String startDate) {
    this(name, Instant.parse(startDate));
}
```

The `Instant` class is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

I am exploiting the fact that your strings are in the ISO 8601 format for an instant, the format that `Instant.parse` accepts and parses.

**Avoid `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`**

I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. There is also an error in your format pattern string for parsing: `Z` (pronounced “Zulu”) means UTC, and of you don’t parse it as such, you will get incorrect times (on most JVMs). `Instant.parse` efficiently avoids any problems here.

**Don’t store date-tine as a string**

It looks like you are are storing start time in a `String` field in your object? That would be poor modelling. Use a proper date-time type. Strings are for interfaces. Date-time classes like `Instant` offer much more functionality, for example define sort order.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main approaches:

- Make your class implement Comparable
- Use a custom Comparator

Then, you can choose the field to compare from, and transform it.

IE (implementing comparable):

```
class Example implements Comparable<Example> { 

    private String stringDate; 

    public int compareTo(Example e) { 
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date date1 = formatter.parse(this.stringDate);
        Date date2 = formatter.parse(e.stringDate);
        return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime(); 
    } 
}
```

And then using Arrays.sort would use your custom comparison.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the old java date API instead of the new modern `java.time`?

Comment: If `stringDate` really has the given pattern, then there wouldn't be a need to parsing the String to a Date. Natural String sorting would be enough.

Comment: Why are you not taking advantage of the fact that Date implements `Comparable` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Let your class implement `Comparable` and implement `compareTo` using modern formatting and date classes. Note that `LocalDateTime` also implements Comparable so once the string has been parsed you let `LocalDateTime` do the comparison

```
public class MyTimes implements Comparable<MyTimes>  {
     private final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;

     //other code

     public int compareTo(MyTimes o) {
         LocalDateTime thisDate = LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(this.getStartTime()));
         LocalDateTime otherDate = LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(o.getStartTime()));
         return thisDate.compareTo(otherDate);
     }
}
```

You can also create a separate class as a comparator if this comparison is special and what you not always want to use

```
public class MyTimesComparator implements Comparator<MyTimes> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyTimes arg0, MyTimes arg1) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
        LocalDateTime thisDate = LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(this.getStartTime()));
        LocalDateTime otherDate = LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(o.getStartTime()));
        return thisDate.compareTo(otherDate);
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
someList.sort(new MyTimesComparator());
```

or use an inline function (I am using `Instant` here)

```
someList.sort( (m1, m2) -> {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
    Instant instant1 = Instant.from(dtf.parse(m1.getStartTime));
    Instant instant2 = Instant.from(dtf.parse(m2.getStartTime));
    return intant1.compareTo(instant2);
});
```

I noticed now that you have an array and not a list so you need to convert to a list or use Arrays.sort instead.

Comment: Thanks for showing the use of `Instant` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Using `Instant` is more correct since the string is in this format. From trying to convert to `LocalDateTime` I seem to get `java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1478866394},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`.